# problem generating argv for spawnvp()

Tags: c, argv

I need to run a command using *spawnvp()*, so I can redirect the output. My problem is, that I don't have argv, but just a string with the whole commnd, so I need to split it. Unfortunately I got an exception when I passed my generated argv into the function.

Doing it this way works:

```
char* argv[2];
argv[0] = "kzip";
argv[1] = NULL;
```

This is the way I am doing it, which is failing:

```
char** argv2 = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
argv2[0] = "kzip";
argv2[1] = NULL;
```

This is how I call *spawnvp()*:

```
hProcess = (HANDLE)spawnvp(P_NOWAIT, argv2[0], (const char* const*)&argv2);
```

I know there is some difference between a char[] and a char*, but I can't figure out how to create a dynamically created char*[] instead of a char**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't put my hand in the fire for it but you should drop the `&` from this line.

```
hProcess = (HANDLE)spawnvp(P_NOWAIT, argv2[0], (const char* const*)&argv2);
```

`argv == &argv` but `argv2 != &argv2`

Answer (score 1):

Your last argument to spawnvp is wrong, it should be just `spawnvp(P_NOWAIT, argv2[0], argv2);` , and not the address of your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Using spawnxx() to redirect output is not a good idea. It's better to use popen() and construct the command string to redirect appropriately, e.g. if you would like to redirect stdout and stderr from command.exe into somefile.txt:

```
popen("command.exe &> somefile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shell-style command line, you should spawn with this argv:

```
(char []){ "sh", "-c", command, 0 }
```